# Should I still define _GNU_SOURCE when I compile with -std=gnu99?

Tags: c, gcc, gnu

I use some GNU extensions and realized that if I set gnu99 as C-standard to use, I can omit #define _GNU_SOURCE. Does gnu99 imply the _GNU_SOURCE or is it still safer to use it or mandatory to avoid problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should differentiate between language and library features; -std=gnu99 enables GNU language features, _GNU_SOURCE enables GNU library features.

I suggest you to define _GNU_SOURCE if you use any library features, so it's clear for readers of your code. Also, this might make things more obvios when your code is (not) compiling on a platform that provides GCC but not glibc.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense to me, since I also use getline. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: `getline` is in POSIX 2008 and should be exposed by default on modern glibc versions, but for the sake of supporting old ones you might want to use `_GNU_SOURCE`.

Comment: Yes, I've read that in the official documentation. I leave _GNU_SOURCE to be on the save side.